# How to bind to a login event when using MVC and Windows Authentication?

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

Given that I am using *Windows Authentication* (AuthenticationTypes.Kerberos) *MVC6-beta2* with *Identity-Framework-7-beta2*: I have code that I would like to run the first time a user authenticates to the application for a particular session.

As I understand it, IIS handles the Windows Authentication logic, then hands the request to the MVC router that then hands it to the appropriate controller based on the request URL.  So any controller could in theory, service the user's first request.

**Is there a way to bind to an event at a central place such as the MVC router or ServerInformation.Listener to get at this windows Kerberos login/authentication event?**

Comment: Still looking for the answer to this.  I discovered when using windows authentication, the IPrincipal Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.RazorRazorPage.User refers to the windows identity of the current user and not the IdentityFramework user identity for the user.  Any claims the IdentityFramework user has are related to claims on the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.RazorRazorPage.User object.

Comment: [Authorize("Administrator", "Allow")] appears to compare claim possession on the IPrincipal.identity or the 'current principal' rather than any claims assigned within Identity Framework.

Comment: did you got any answer